# modular concept with entity framework code first and self-contained migration support for each module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

i would like to have a modular webapp as this example:

**appCore**:

- contains [dbContext-instance, core-tables, core-data, ...]

**appModuleA**:

- requires [appCore]
- contains [moduleA-tables, moduleA-data, moduleA-logic, usage of appCore ...]

**appModuleB**:

- requires [appCore, appModuleA]
- contains [moduleB-tables, moduleB-data, moduleB-logic, usage of appCore AND moduleA ...]

etc.

dynamic loading of entities is no problem and i solved this problem as described here: http://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/

but how can i implement a migration support of each module without using AutomaticMigrationEnabled = true?

I hope I have formulated my problem understandable. :-)

thank you.

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- **ONE LARGE CONTEXT**
  with all tables declared

or 3 contexts

- **CORE**
- **MODULE A ONLY**
- **MODULE B Only**

You can even add other unrelated tables to the DB manually.

However dont try and OVERLAP contexts for MIGRATION purposes. (Preferred initializer)

Contexts that overlap for data access purposes , no problem. (Initializer NUll)

> Search for topic: Bounded Contexts and Entity Framework